# ssh authentication to an AFS using public/private key pairs

Tags: bash, ssh, authentication, afs

I'm writing a lil' bash script to update files on a webserver from any authorized computer. In the end, I want to use the scp command to do the work.

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $localpath $user@gpu.srv.ualberta.ca:$webpath
```

The webserver is on an AFS, so dropping the public key into **~/.ssh/authenticated_keys** doesn't cut it, as you need a token to access that. One workaround, as described in [1],"is to place private keys into **~/.ssh-private** and place public keys into **~/.ssh/authorized_keys**. The access to **~/.ssh-private** is closed off to everyone but the user, while the access to **~/.ssh** is opened up to unauthenticated users."

I'd love to do this, but I'm not the network admin. I can ssh 'manually' by supplying the password. Is there a way for me to figure out how it's been arranged? How is it usually done?

I found a [Kerberos/AFS patch for ssh](http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Software/SSH/patch_repository/descriptions/AFS_KRB5.html), but don't want to dive into it until I get some feedback. (I'd likely just break my OSX ssh command!)

[1] cs.unc.edu/cgi-bin/howto?howto=ssh-keys
(Sorry about the link -- I'm only allowed to make one active.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need to be root to place files in `~` (e.g. via `scp`)?

For the confused there is always `ssh-copy-id`. To install your public key from your local machine you would

`# ssh-copy-id $user@gpu.srv.ualberta.ca`

This will automagically guess your which key to install. For everything else have a look at the manpage.

Comment: "$user" doesn't have root permissions.

I talked to the IT guys that manage the server -- they haven't made provisions for any workaround and couldn't think of any, so I buggered off.

Comment: @tyblu did you try ssh-copy-id? If I understand you correctly, you don't need root to set this up.